# why have I an IndexError when running my Django project?

Tags: python

when I runserver it returns an `IndexError`:"list assignment index out of range".
Because of my file rasp.py in line 15 but I did't found the reason.

rasp.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def foo ( ) :
    tab=  [ ]
    i = 0
    for i in range(12):
        tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000007101990/w1_slave")
        text = tfile.read()
        tfile.close()
        secondline = text.split("\n")[1]
        temp = secondline.split(" ")[9]
        temperature  = float(temp[2:])
        temperature = temperature/1000
        mystr = str(temperature)
        mystring = mystr.replace(",",".")
        tab [i] = mystring
    return tab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving an `IndexError` because you are trying to access an index that is not existing in the list.

Instead of accessing it by index, you could use the method `append`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def foo ( ) :
    tab=  []
    for i in range(12):
        tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000007101990/w1_slave")
        text = tfile.read()
        tfile.close()
        secondline = text.split("\n")[1]
        temp = secondline.split(" ")[9]
        temperature  = float(temp[2:])
        temperature = temperature/1000
        mystr = str(temperature)
        mystring = mystr.replace(",",".")
        tab.append(mystring)
    return tab
```

Answer (score 0):

`tab` is an empty list, which means that it has no valid indices, which is why `tab[i] = mystring` raises an `IndexError`. Use `tab.append(mystring)`, which will append the value to the end of the string